# Twilio Application Failed Message

Tags: twilio, voice

I have been trying to build a app that redirect a Twilio number to another phone number when a customer call Twilio number.
When callback URL does not return proper Twilml, it says "Application has failed" message on the call.
However, I do not want my customers hear that message even though there is a error.
Is there a way to turn that message off?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

There is no way to disable the error message, but you can set a [Fallback URL](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/security/availability-reliability) on your phone number that Twilio will request in case the Voice Request URL fails.

You could set the Fallback URL to a simple static XML file hosted somewhere like Amazon or Dropbox, or use a service like twimlbin.com to host some backup TwiML for you.